# Google Chrome console filter out groups

Tags: google-chrome

In the Google Chrome Developer tools, I have output from the Google Analytics debugger extension that dumps too much output into my console.

[image]

I am aware that there is a filter to allow you to filter messages. However, a large part of what the Google Analytics debugger outputs are statements enclosed by `console.group` and `console.groupend`.

While I can use the filter to filter out the text in the group, is there a way to filter out the group bars as well?

Second image showing filtered console

[image]

As you can see, while a bunch of text inside the collapsed groups is hidden, the groups themselves are not, and there are currently a few hundred of those that are making it difficult for me to find my debug messages

Comment: This is a known bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=363796